# For the same ID in one column of SQL, how do I write a Case statement for the row with the greater value in the another column?

Tags: sql, if-statement, conditional-statements, case

In SQL, for the same set of ID, I want to create the column `Action` with `New` where the `Contract Number` is the largest and `Old` for the smaller values.

For example, for `ID = 123`, the largest value in `Contract Number` is 10, so that row will be marked as `New` and the others as `Old`. The only columns in the SQL database are `ID` and `Contract Number`, so I'm assuming I should use a `CASE WHEN` statement to create the `Action` column, but not sure how to formulate it

Sample table:

| ID | Contract Number |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 10 |
| 123 | 5 |
| 123 | 3 |
| 456 | 3 |
| 456 | 2 |

Expected output:

| ID | Contract Number | Action |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 10 | Keep |
| 123 | 5 | Old |
| 123 | 3 | Old |
| 456 | 3 | Keep |
| 456 | 2 | Old |

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not as images.

Comment: @jarlh - Thanks, just edited my question. Hope this is clear now

Comment: Much better. Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @jarlh - It's a company created dbms so it's an internal platform. But it uses MySQL commands typically

Answer (score 1):

You could use a case expression together with a windowed aggregate:

```
select *, 
  case when 
    contractnumber = Max(ContractNumber) over(partition by Id) then 'Keep'
  else 'Old' end Action
from sampledata;
```

Comment: Thank you Stu!  I have another question for this example (https://ibb.co/wB60cJs). For the same ID, the IDs that have a Date in the future should be flagged as "Keep".  I used a OVER(PARTITION BY() with a MIN and MAX, but my script only flagged the top row as "Keep" and the remaining as "Old" for ID 123. How do I write my script so that all future dates are flagged as "Keep"?

Answer (score 1):

I like using Common Table Expressions (CTEs) for this

```
  --get the max value 
  ;with CN as (select max(ContractNumber) as MaxContractNumber, ID
  FROM [SampleDb].[dbo].[SampleDataforSO]
  group by ID,ContractNumber)
  --loop through and assign the relevant action item for the max value
  select s.ID, s.ContractNumber,
  case
  when ContractNumber < max(MaxContractNumber) then 'Old'
  when ContractNumber = max(MaxContractNumber) then 'Keep'
  end as 'Action'
  from CN
  join [SampleDb].[dbo].[SampleDataforSO] s
  on s.ID = cn.ID
  group by s.id, ContractNumber
```

output:
[image: output]